# How to display category link in wordpress recent posts widget?

Tags: php

I`m trying hard to display the category link for each post in Recent Posts widget, but nothing helps.. Every time i get an error

```
$category = get_the_category();
```

and then

```
<?php if ( $show_category ) : ?>
    <a href="" class="category-link"><?php  echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but it displays category in strange way: on the main page its always first category, for any post, when im reading the post - curent post category is shown for any post in widget. I really have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$cats = get_the_category();
    if(count($cats)){
        $cat = $cats[0];
        $cat = sprintf('<a href="%s" id="cat-%s">%s</a>',get_category_link($cat->cat_ID), $cat->cat_ID, $cat->cat_name );
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesnt work for me, im trying to add this to class WP_Widget__Recent_Posts code, but its no result